# Find position in plane with pointing device returning unit vectors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to use a Joy-Con (from Nintendo Switch) as an input device for a computer by pointing at the screen and emulate the mouse cursor. But at the moment I am stuck at converting the output from the Joy-Con to the position on the screen.

The Joy-Con outputs a three-dimensional unit vector. The idea was to point first at the edges of the screen ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$) and record the corresponding output unit vectors ($\vec{v}_1$, $\vec{v}_2$, $\vec{v}_3$, $\vec{v}_4$) as a setup procedure (see attached sketch). And then calculate the projection for an arbitrary vector onto the screen. But since the four initial vectors do not originate from the same point (as the hand moves when pointing at the four edges) and the distance might vary, I cannot use a simple projection, as for example with a camera where all direction vectors have the same origin.

Is it possible to map a direction (when pointed on the screen) to a position on the screen?

Thanks in advance,

George

[image: Sketch]

Comment: Have you any way to get not only direction vector but also data about origin position (maybe position of center of square formed by origin points of vectors $\vec{v}_i$ from your drawing)?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Unfortunatelly not, but I could get an additional unit-vector pointing in the middle of the screen by adding a fifth point in the setup procedure in the middle of the screen if that helps.

Comment: 1. I think you will need to re-setup device after changing position of JoyCon (distance from screen, height, left-right position). 2. To use data you can either use point projection from location of JoyCon or from point of intersection of lines containing vectors $\vec{v}_i$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu The distance does not change anymore after the setup process. Only the initial length might vary from setup to setup procedure